# C++ best way to define cross-file constants

Tags: c++, templates, constants, extern

I am working on a game and have an interesting question. I have some game-wide constant values that I want to implement in one file. Right now I have something like this:

constants.cpp

```
extern const int BEGINNING_HEALTH = 10;
extern const int BEGINNING_MANA = 5;
```

constants.hpp

```
extern const int BEGINNING_HEALTH;
extern const int BEGINNING_MANA;
```

And then files just #include "constants.hpp"
This was working great, until I needed to use one of the constants as a template parameter, because externally-linked constants are not valid template parameters.
So my question is, what is the best way to implement these constants? I am afraid that simply putting the constants in a header file will cause them to be defined in each translation unit. And I don't want to use macros.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Get rid of the `extern` and you're set.

This code works perfectly fine in a header, because everything is "truly constant" and therefore has internal linkage:

```
const int BEGINNING_HEALTH = 10;
const int BEGINNING_MANA = 5;
const char BEGINNING_NAME[] = "Fred";
const char *const BEGINNING_NAME2 = "Barney";
```

This code cannot safely be put in a header file because each line has external linkage (either explicitly or because of not being truly constant):

```
extern const int BEGINNING_HEALTH = 10;
extern const int BEGINNING_MANA = 5;
const char *BEGINNING_NAME = "Wilma";  // the characters are const, but the pointer isn't
```

Comment: i suspect a copy/paste bug in last BEGINNING_NAME[] one. did you want to write it as BEGINNING_NAME ?

Comment: You need "static", otherwise you do not get internal linkage or, more ideally, the equivalent of a "#define" with the values inlined.

Comment: @Jim Buck constants in C++ have internal linkage - no need for "static"

Answer (score 10):

How about enums?

constants.hpp

```
  enum {
    BEGINNING_HEALTH = 10,
    BEGINNING_MANA = 5
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use "static const int" in your .hpp file, and put nothing in the .cpp file (except whatever other code you have there of course).

Answer (score 4):

make use of namespaces:

```
namespace GameBeginning {
    const int HEALTH = 10;
    const int MANA   = 5; 
};
```

then u can use as player.health = GameBeginning::HEALTH;

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers simply don't allocate space for const POD values. They optimize them out and treat them as if they had been `#define`d, don't they?

Comment: Close, but still not quite the same.  Example where macros work but constants don't: #define FOO "foo"; \ const char *str = "bar" FOO;  C and C++ allow concatenation of string literal tokens, but not string constants.

Comment: This is only true for integral constants.  Floats, doubles, char*s, and other types will be allocated storage if optimization is disabled.

Comment: @Tom: That's not what I meant. I meant for POD constants, not preprocessor majicks. I meant in the sense that the symbol and the space for the value don't exist unless you attempt to take its address.

Comment: I think POD officially includes floats and doubles, but floats and doubles are generally not optimized in this way.

Answer (score 0):

What ever happened to a simple:

```
#define BEGINNING_HEALTH 10
```

Man, those were the days.
Oh wait, those **still are** the days!

Comment: That might not do what you're expecting in the context of template parameters... :) rlbond needs that.

Comment: Some of us like our debuggers to show 'BEGINNING_HEALTH' instead of '10'.

Comment: <sarcastic> When needs debuggers when you have printf()?  </sarcastic>

Comment: printf, #define, what next. This is C++.

Answer (score -2):

perhaps something along the lines of a static class?

```
class CONSTANTS {
public:
static inline int getMana() { return 10;};
};
```

Comment: That doesn't help.  Function values cannot be used as template parameters.  C++0x keyword `constexpr` is supposed to work around that.

Besides, C++ has namespaces, which are superioer to a static class for "namespacing" constants.

Answer (score -5):

As a quick answer to the title question, a singleton pattern is a possible best, C++ way to define cross-file constants and insure only one instance of the object.

As far as the template parameter problem, you need to pass a type not a value.  Your type is "int".

Comment: This seems like overkill for a set of simple constants, and is not likely to solve his problems with template instantiation.

Comment: Why wouldn't is solve his problem with template instantiation, since it wouldn't be an extern, it would be a local.  Overkill is relative, what is the quality perspective $100M, $100K, or $100 game budget?

Comment: jeffD, the problem is that your answer does not make sense. do you want to make an "int" a singleton? an int is comprised by value, not by identity. another thing that probably made people downvote you is that he doesn't want to pass a type, but a value to his template. Why do you say he can't?

Comment: The title to the question is a good question by itself.  Maybe I do need to see more of his code. See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates.html for a ref. "A template parameter is a special kind of parameter that can be used to pass a type as argument".  Wish comments allowed hyperlinks.

Comment: Nice, the http address automatically becomes hyperized.

Comment: jeffD, unfortunately, the tutorial at cplusplus.com isn't quite good - too incomplete and sometimes wrong. for example template declarations are not "expressions" as they say, they are declarations. blurs out the difference between a specialization and an explicit specialization on their page too.

Comment: better get a good book (there are some good threads on SO about C++ books) rather than relying on cplusplus.com . even for a reference, it has some quite blatantly wrong pages (i wonder whether they still maintain them?). and please read the very end on that linked page (about non-type parameters).

Comment: For the record, you can pass integral values to templates (Boost.Array uses this ability, I believe).

Comment: jeffD,
I have a Matrix class that is uses a static array. Its class signature is 
template <typename T, int Rows, int Columns> class Matrix.
This is perfectly legal C++ code.

Comment: I stand by my answer to the title question.  You may be right about what he's doing w/ templates, w/o seeing the code and error it's unsure.  There are really two questions here, I think I'll pose one as a seperate question.