# Compilation error when typedef an std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, stdarray

I define a type called `inputTy` using `std::array` (c++11) , the dimension of the array declared as an external constant integer `d`.

```
namespace project {
  namespace types{
    extern const int d;
    typedef std::array<double, d> inputTy;
  }
}
```

Why  do I  get such compilation error?

```
../../include/types.h:16:29: error: the value of ‘d’ is not usable in a constant expression
 typedef std::array<double, d> inputTy;
                             ^
../../include/types.h:15:18: note: ‘d’ was not initialized with a constant expression
 extern const int d;
              ^
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the value of `d` must be compile-time constant. When it is extern, how should the compiler know?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the requirements for C++ template parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643763/what-are-the-requirements-for-c-template-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `extern const int` as array size because compiler does not know the size of a constant from other compilation unit.

Change your design to use `std::vector` or some other container to overcome the problem or put the constant in a header and include it before `typede`fing.